# Сложные функции: использовать ли промежуточные переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, math

Пусть имеются 2 функции, выполняющие некоторые арифметические действия:

```
def f(x):
    # some code here

def g(y):
    # some other code here
```

Какая реализация сложной функции правильнее (/быстрее/оптимальнее/...)?

1.

```
a = f(x)
b = g(a)
```

2.

```
b = g(f(x))
```

Comment: По-моему, второй вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. нам как минимум не надо думать об утилизации переменной `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверим:

```
from datetime import datetime


def f(i):
    return i + 1


def g(i):
    return i * 2

n = 10000000

t = datetime.now()
for _ in range(n):
    a = f(1)
    b = g(a)
print(datetime.now() - t)

t = datetime.now()
for _ in range(n):
    b = g(f(1))
print(datetime.now() - t)
```

Прогнал несколько раз, цифры каждый раз получались примерно одинаковые:

Первый вариант: 2,1-2,3 секунды

Второй вариант: 1,8-2,0 секунды

Как и следовало ожидать, в первом случае создание и утилизация дополнительной переменной занимает какое-то дополнительное время.

Однако, следует понимать, что разница начинает ощущаться только на очень большом числе повторений (у меня их было 10 миллионов).
Тем более, что функции я взял совсем уж элементарные - из одного простейшего арифметического действия. Любая более сложная функция будет занимать больше времени, и затраты на ещё одну переменную на этом фоне будут не так уж и заметны.

Так что в реальности следует предпочесть тот из двух вариантов, который будет проще читаться.
Кроме случаев, когда вам нужно писать совсем уж тяжёлую числомолотилку с жёсткими требованиями по скорости работы - на на такой задаче вообще стоит использовать не чистый питон, а вставки на C/C++ или Numba.

Comment: На практике могут быть использованы оба варианта. И основной критерий это читаемость кода (осмысленные имена переменных могут в этом помочь). О производительности здесь стоит думать, только если profiler скажет что введение имён является узким местом в вашей программе (маловероятно). В любом случае разница в пределах погрешности измерений. Для измерения производительности, вместо datetime лучше `timeit` модуль использовать ([`timeit.default_timer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279)). Или `perf` команду:  `python -m perf timeit -s 'g=lambda i:i*2;f=lambda i: i+1' 'g(f(1))'`

Comment: вот [гистограммы результатов измерений времени для наглядности](https://gist.github.com/zed/59fcde0cbf495b802defb7da8d3f830c)

Comment: еще возможен вариант: `def g(i): return f(i) * 2`

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov, только в этом случае у нас g оказывает намертво завязана на f, и смысла делать их двумя отдельными функциями нет вообще (ну, только если с целью лучшей читаемости). А в изначальных примерах мы могли когда нам нужно вызвать g и с аргументом f(i), а когда нужно - с любым другим аргументом.

Comment: @Александр само собой, что это частный случай, однако, этот вариант  показывает тайминги лучше, чем вышеуказанные: [пример](https://repl.it/MtWb)

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov, а какой смысл в лучших таймингах, если ваш код не равнозначен приведённому? Можно вообще внутри цикла писать b=4, это то же значение, которое получилось бы в результате всех вычислений, и тайминги были бы вообще прекрасными. А можно даже и цикл не гонять, раз значение всё равно на каждой итерации одинаковым получается - и получить ускорение на семь порядков. Но вопрос то был не про это.

Comment: @Александр в вопросе вторая функция завязана на результат первой, так что данный случай - равнозначен

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov, во-первых, если вопросе в качестве примера приведён какой-то частный случай, то это именно пример, и именно частный случай, и автор хочет ответ на вопрос, а не чтобы вы решили приведённый пример. А вопрос был именно про то, как правильнее вызвать одну существующую функцию от результата выполнения другой существующей функции. А не про то, как эти функции переписать.

Comment: @Александр, это быссмысленная полемика. Я и не претендовал на ответ, я просто указал, что для конкретно этого частного случая - такой вызов будет наиболее оптимальным